# Redirecting .app domain to Amazon S3 bucket (SSL)

Tags: ssl-certificate, redirect, amazon-s3, website, static-content

I'm currently hosting a static website on an Amazon s3 bucket (i.e. `https://s3.eu-east-2.amazonaws.com/MyApp/index.html`) and I have recently bought an .app domain which I would like to redirect to the bucket (i.e. `myapp.app`). 
I have configured the DNS in order to perform a redirection with masking, but when I insert it in my browser it get marked as unsafe. 
Apparently the .app domains always require an SSL certificate. Do I need a separate certificate even if I'm redirecting to a website supporting an SSL connection?

Comment: I don't think redirects and such is the way to go. I suspect you need to use CloudFront to enable https delivery of your static website that's stored in S3. A quick search found [this tutorial](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-make-use-of-cloudfront-for-secure-delivery-of-static-websites-to-the-world-d2f54e8b096).

Comment: I will give it a try!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the whole `.APP` TLD is added in the HSTS preloading list, used by all major browsers. So no browser will do an HTTP query to a `.APP` domain name they will all first and only do an HTTPS query.

This specific point should have been highlighted to you by your registrar when you brought the `.APP` domain name as this was to be enforced by Google contract with your registrar.

So whatever you point your website to needs to respond correctly on port 443.

See this other answer from me for all the details on `.APP`, TLS and HSTS: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50258651/6368697